# Constructing a Maximum Entropy Classifier for Sentence Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, gradient-descent

So I'm reading this paper which uses a [max ent classifier for sentence extraction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8f54/b66017b99c4ee525e91f389f9f6417cf2e88.pdf). The parametric form for a conditional max ent model is :

$$ P(c|s) = \frac{1}{Z(s)} \exp \sum_i \lambda_if_i(c,s)$$

where $f_i(c,s)$ is a feature which has a weight $\lambda_i$ associated with it.

Now, the paper states that *conjugate descent was used to find the optimal set of weights* (page 3) - and this is what I'm unable to comprehend. How to use/apply **conjugate gradient descent** to calculate the optimal set of weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conjugate gradient descent** is a variation on gradient descent. **Gradient descent** is a method of finding the minimum of a function by taking steps that reduce the error between the data and the model parameters. **Conjugate gradient descent** extends gradient descent by searching a plane, instead of a line. The plane is defined as a linear combination of the gradient vector and the previous descent step vector. **Conjugate gradient descent** is very good at finding the solutions to a set of sparse linear equations.

**Gradient descent** and variations are general methods for finding the best parameters. The best practice is to define your specific model and then call on a separate gradient descent package to search for optimal values (i.e., hyperparameters) for the model.